# mirador 3 - jump to page / set page / set canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iiif

How to load Mirador3 on specific page via config or method call?

It would be great to load viewer on page 3 without knowing canvas@id from iiif manifest.
Manifest has the sequence defined - jumping to page should be easy. (or not?)

I found [setCanvas](https://github.com/ProjectMirador/mirador/blob/49f4e0ab518730bc73eeaa3eae55a96c39d83e26/src/state/actions/canvas.js#L15) in source.
Also found this [plugin](https://github.com/sul-dlss/mirador-jump-to-page/blob/master/jump_to_page.js) (but that is for Mirador 2 - I think).

Only thing that works atm is manifest property `startCanvas`

- https://iiif.io/api/presentation/2.0/#linking-properties
  But I want to cache my manifests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mirador 3 provides some APIs for you to use to accomplish this. You can either initialize a window with a given `canvasIndex` or set the canvas to a known `canvasId`.

1. You can initialize a window with a `canvasIndex` property to start on a specific index.

```
var miradorInstance = Mirador.viewer({
  id: 'mirador',
  windows: [{
    id: 'known-window-id',
    canvasIndex: 3
    loadedManifest: 'https://iiif.harvardartmuseums.org/manifests/object/299843',
  }],
});
```

2. You can programmatically set the canvas if you know the canvasId

```
var miradorInstance = Mirador.viewer({
  id: 'mirador',
  windows: [{
    id: 'known-window-id',
    loadedManifest: 'https://iiif.harvardartmuseums.org/manifests/object/299843',
  }],
});
// We create the action first. Note we are using a specified `windowId` here. This could be accessed from the store instead of specifying upfront.
var action = Mirador.actions.setCanvas('known-window-id', 'https://iiif.harvardartmuseums.org/manifests/object/299843/canvas/canvas-43182083')
// Now we can dispatch it.
miradorInstance.store.dispatch(action);
```

See https://github.com/ProjectMirador/mirador/wiki/M3---Mirador-3-Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-canvas

If you do not know the `canvasId` in advance, option 1 is probably the best for you to do.

Comment: `canvasIndex: 3` is a neat feature - just what I needed. Maybe it could be added this to docs... I am not a React user so store actions are not so useful in my project.

Comment: Worth noting that `canvasIndex` iz zero based