# Mirador 3: adding attributes to HTML elements inside the viewer

Tags: mirador

On a database website, I am using a [build of the Mirador 3 viewer with two extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74076747/mirador-3-setting-different-configuration-options-when-using-build-with-plug-in).

I would like to use [intro.js](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js) to create a tutorial that highlights the main elements in the viewer and explains their functions to the user.

To do this, I need to add attributes to the HTML elements I want highlighted (`data-title`, `data-intro`, to tell **intro.js** what tutorial text to display).

**UPDATE: this is [not actually necessary](https://introjs.com/docs/examples/basic/json-config) - I can just specify the steps using JSON, and point to selectors for existing elements. However, the question of easily adding attributes to elements in the Mirador viewer is still relevant, even if not needed in the intro.js case**

What's the easiest way to add these data attributes? Ideally, I would like to add these at the point of creating the Mirador build.

Answer (score 0):

we discussed your question at a community call and we think this would ideally be developed as a plugin. For what it's worth, this idea was discussed some time back in the Mirador community. I'm sharing the link in case it provides any further insights for you: https://github.com/ProjectMirador/mirador/issues/3316. In the meantime, please feel free to join us on the #mirador channel of the IIIF Community Slack, or at one of our upcoming community calls when you’re available!